# Relative date value user defined variables

Tags: datetime, jmeter

How can I create a user defined variable that has a relative date e.g. current date plus 1 year?

I have created a user define variable `startDate`
I have tried adding the code

`LocalDate.now().plusYears(1).toString();`

in multiple paces but I just can't get the variable value to be set by the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function:

```
 ${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,${startDate},P1D,,)}
```

> The timeShift function returns a date in the given format with the specified amount of seconds, minutes, hours, days or months added

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [`java.time` package](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/) into your expression

The correct syntax for the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) would be:

```
${__groovy(java.time.LocalDate.now().plusYears(1).toString(),startDate)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how/)